# How to delete unknown user input from console in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After running this code , if i put anything either "yes" or "no", its response appears in console, is possible to simply just delete that and just appears "Wrong answer." ?

```
import random

print("The random number is:")

for x in range(1):
    print(random.randint(1, 6))

while True:

    answer = input("Do you want to roll again? 'yes' or 'no' ")

    print(answer)

    if answer == 'yes':
        for x in range(1):
            print("The new number is:")
            print(random.randint(1, 6))


    elif answer == 'no':
        print("Thanks for playing.")
        break

    else:
        print("Wrong answer.")
        break
```

Comment: is it not easier to print the answer only in the wanted cases ?

Comment: But if the user put anything eihter yes or no , appears in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to only print `answer` in the cases Yes or No :

```
while True:
    answer = input("Do you want to roll again? 'yes' or 'no' : ")

    if answer.lower() in ['y','yes', 'of course']:
        print('Yes')
        for x in range(1):
            print("The new number is:")
            print(random.randint(1, 6))


    elif answer.lower() in ['n', 'no', 'never']:
        print('No')
        print("Thanks for playing.")
        break

    else:
        print("Wrong answer.")
```

I just changed the possible answers to allow other answers (more flexible case-insensitive, add other words...)

Also, i removed the break in `else` statement, i think you should let a chance to users who made typos :)

(I'm not sure you need a for loop to get the random number)

Comment: Works perfectly , just like i want to, i just add a "break" after print "("Wrong answer.")". if i not put that break was print again "Do you want to roll again?"

Comment: @AndréMartins  thank for the feedback, only you can decide what users are allowed to do